# How to run the Deck.gl getting started examples

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

I am a newbie in terms of react, js and deck.gl and would like to run the basic [getting started example](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/overview/getting-started) from deck.gl:

Where do I put this code, which extension do I use, do I need other files e.g. `app.js` to run this:

```
import DeckGL from 'deck.gl/react';
import {ArcLayer} from 'deck.gl';

const flights = new ArcLayer({
  id: 'flights',
  data: [] // Some flight points
});

<DeckGL width={1920} height={1080} layers={[flights]} />
```

I am really sorry for the vague question, but I really would like the necessary steps to get this examples working on a Mac. 
Do I need to install a react app? How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have now setup pretty straightforward examples you can directly clone and start toying with, even if you don't have any previous knowledge of [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) or [deck.gl](/questions/tagged/deck.gl).

You just need to go to one of the [examples](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/tree/master/examples), let's do it with the webpack 2 hello-world.

Before anything, you need to go to the [MapBox website](https://www.mapbox.com), create an account and generate an API key, that will be used to render the tiles of the map. Once you have it, just export it as an environment variable:

```
export MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=42eufr5aeoushanoeu
```

Then you can actually start doing the following:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:uber/deck.gl.git
cd examples/hello-world-webpack2
npm install
npm start
```

And you should be good to go, the `app.js` file is the only thing to change in order to change layers or the map in itself.

<sub>Disclaimer: I work at Uber with the Visualization team that made deck.gl.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: 
Here is a good recent walkthrough of someone experimenting with [deck.gl](http://nghiatran.me/deck-gl-data-visualization/)
Source: [@github.NghiaTranUIT](https://github.com/NghiaTranUIT/data-visualization-deck-gl)

---

Looking at the examples there are two things to note.

1. You need data within the data field
2. You need react and other dependences

---

**From getting started**

```
import DeckGL from 'deck.gl/react';
import {ArcLayer} from 'deck.gl';

const flights = new ArcLayer({
  id: 'flights',
  data: [] // data field needs to have data
});

<DeckGL width={1920} height={1080} layers={[flights]} />
```

they omit how the data should be structured (hence where you might have problems).

The other thing is that the library is dependent on using react

**from hello-world-webpack2**
[package.json](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/hello-world-webpack2/package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
  "deck.gl": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
  "luma.gl": "^3.0.0",
  "react": "^15.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
  "react-map-gl": "^2.0.0"
},
```

So following those examples, you'll need to have react to run your own project with deck.gl.

I'd recommend looking at the examples on github to get a better understanding on how to run a starter project.